# I cannot query if there are duplicate in mysql database//

Tags: php, sql

I have a website that searches for an order id and echoes it on php if it found that id. The problem is if there is a duplicate id it does not query it properly.

I have tried searching the web for answers

```
<?php
require('connect.php');

$order_id = $_POST['order_id'];

$conn = mysqli_connect("", "", "", ""); 
$query = "SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE order_id='$order_id' ";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$count = mysqli_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1) {

    $sql = "SELECT `order_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `order_name`, 
                    `qty`, `price`, `total`, `reg_date`, `status` 
            FROM `orders` 
            WHERE order_id='$order_id'";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);


    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


        echo"<div id='orders'>";
            echo "ORDER NUMBER: " . $row["order_id"];
                echo"<br>";
                echo"<br>";
            echo "FIRST NAME: " . $row["firstname"];
                echo"<br>";
                echo"<br>";
            echo "LAST NAME: " . $row["lastname"];
                echo"<br>";
                echo"<br>";
            echo "ORDER: " . $row["order_name"];
                echo"<br>";
                echo"<br>";
            echo "QUANTITY: " . $row["qty"];
                echo"<br>";
                echo"<br>";
            echo "PRICE: " . $row["price"];
                echo"<br>";
                echo"<br>";
            echo "ORDER TOTAL: " . $row["total"];
                echo"<br>";
                echo"<br>";
            echo "STATUS: " . $row["status"];
                echo"<br>";
                echo"<br>";
            echo "DATE ORDERED: " . $row["reg_date"];

            echo"</div>";
        }
    }else{
        echo"<div id='orders'>";
        echo"INVALID ID ENTERED";
        echo"</div>";

}
?>
```

The result returns an "INVALID ID ENTERED" if there are two duplicate results in mysqli data base. I know that I can just simply change the order id so that it does not have to be duplicated but that is not what I wanted.

Comment: Can you show us the schema for this `orders` table please

Comment: Also change this line `echo"INVALID ID ENTERED";` to `echo "INVALID ID ENTERED  Row Count = $count";` and show us that result as well

Comment: _I know that I can just simply change the order id so that it does not have to be duplicated but that is not what I wanted_ Ok, but what did you want to do about this?

Comment: it is returning a

Comment: INVALID ID ENTERED row count = 2

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *` if you only care about the number of rows. Use `SELECT COUNT(*)` and then fetch the result.

Comment: Change `if ($count == 1)` to `if ($count > 0)`.

Comment: There's no need to query twice. You can use the count of the second query.

Answer (score 0):

Don't check if count is 1, check if it's not 0. That way, if there are duplicate orders, you'll show all of them.

There's also no need to do two queries for the same rows. Just do the query that gets the columns you want, and test the count of that.

And use a prepared statement to protect against SQL injection.

```
<?php
require('connect.php');

$order_id = $_POST['order_id'];

$conn = mysqli_connect("", "", "", ""); 
$sql = "SELECT `order_id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `order_name`, 
                `qty`, `price`, `total`, `reg_date`, `status` 
        FROM `orders` 
        WHERE order_id = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $order_id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$count = $stmt->num_rows;

if ($count == 1) {
    $stmt->bind_result($order_id, $firstname, $lastname, $order_name, $qty, $price, $total, $status, $reg_date);
    while($row = $result->fetch()) {
        echo"<div id='orders'>";
        echo "ORDER NUMBER: " . $order_id;
        echo"<br><br>";
        echo "FIRST NAME: " . $firstname;
        echo"<br><br>";
        echo "LAST NAME: " . $lastname;
        echo"<br><br>";
        echo "ORDER: " . $order_name;
        echo"<br><br>";
        echo "QUANTITY: " . $qty;
        echo"<br><br>";
        echo "PRICE: " . $price;
        echo"<br><br>";
        echo "ORDER TOTAL: " . $total;
        echo"<br><br>";
        echo "STATUS: " . $status;
        echo"<br><br>";
        echo "DATE ORDERED: " . $reg_date;
        echo"</div>";
    }
}else{
    echo"<div id='orders'>";
    echo"INVALID ID ENTERED";
    echo"</div>";
}
?>
```